# Why are these terminalsymbols not independent?

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext, xtend

i play a little bit with Xtext and have got an unexpected behaviour in the DSL-editor. Thats not all of the Xtext file but what is important for this issue.

```
Title:   
    title= NOUN  VERB ':';
Use:
   'um' NOUN use=Verbtype;

Verbtype: Simpleverb | NotSeperableVerb;

Simpleverb:
    'zu' simpleverb=VERB;

NotSeperableVerb:
    notseperable=NOTSEPERABLE;

terminal NOTSEPERABLE:
    'be'VERB | 'emp'VERB |'ent'VERB | 'er'VERB | 'ge'VERB | 'miss'VERB | 'ver'VERB | 'zer' VERB;

terminal VERB: ('a'..'z')+;
```

If i write a nonseperable verb for the title section for example "beschreiben" than it is red underlined. I can not explain me that. I want to allow any Verb thus any word which is lower cased at the beginning.

Comment: could you give a complete grammar and sample model? besides that: the lexer (in Antlr and thus in Xtext) is context free. So if it can be lexed as NOTSEPERABLE it will be. Possible solution: have a look at datatype rules (which are parser rules and thus context sensitive)

Answer (score 0):

The terminal symbols `NOTSEPERABLE` and `VERB` aren't independent because they overlap (i.e. they can match some of the same inputs). The only way for terminal rules to not affect each other is for them to not overlap.

The reason for that is that the lexer turns the input into a stream of tokens independently of the parser. The parser simply consumes the tokens generated by the lexer. It does not request specific types of tokens from the lexer and the lexer does not generate different tokens depending on which type the parser needs right now. Instead the lexer generates tokens according to the following logic:

From all terminal rules that can match at the current position in the source code, select the one that produces the longest match. In case of ties, select the one that is defined first in the grammar file. So given the input `beschreiben`, both `VERB` and `NOTSEPERABLE` would produce a match of the same length, so `NOTSEPERABLE` wins because it is defined first.

If you want to match either one, you'll need to define a non-terminal rule that can match either terminal:

```
Verb: NOTSEPERABLE | VERB;
```